# rstudio data table I wish to remodel the database

Tags: r, data.table

I have a database like the one below, I tried with melt but without success.

```
dt_in <- data.table(
  id = 1:11,
  survey_dt = c('2016-03-14', '2018-010-12','2018-03-19', '2018-01-25','2018-08-29', '2018-11-11','2018-06-09', '2018-05-02','2018-07-16', '2018-02-06', NA) ,
  ddn = c('1985-03-14', NA,'1952-02-02', '1961-01-12','1971-06-19', '1969-08-11','1248-11-09', '1956-08-01','1967-09-16', '1989-09-14', NA),
  weight = c(160L, NA, 165L, 180L, 250L,NA ,175L ,NA ,190L, NA),
  queries = c("ok", "not vailable", "ok", "ok", ">220", "not vailable", "< 1900", "not vailable", "ok", "not vailable", "not vailable"),
  center = c("a","a","b","a", "a","b","b","b", "a","b"))
```

I would like to output this format

```
dt_out <- data.table(
  id = c(2,5,6,7,8,10,11,11),
  variable = c("ddn", "weight", "weight", "ddn", "weight", "weight", "survey_dt", "ddn") ,
  queries = c("not available", ">2020", "not available", "<1900", "not available", "not vailable", "not available", "not vailable"),
  value = c("not available","250","not available","1248-11-09","not available", "not available","not available","not available"),
  center = c("a","a","b","b", "b","b","a","a"))
```

Thanks for your help, I'm new to data.table

Comment: Hi mtl. Could you explain a bit about the logic of how you are getting `dt_out` from `dt_in`?

Comment: Hi Allan

I can't transform dt_in into dt_out, that's the subject of my question ;)

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you want to have the values from the columns `ddn`, `weight` and `survey_ddt` in the new column `value`. Then here's a solution using [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) instead of `melt`:

```
dt_in <- tibble(
  id = 1:11,
  survey_dt = c('2016-03-14', '2018-010-12','2018-03-19', '2018-01-25','2018-08-29', '2018-11-11','2018-06-09', '2018-05-02','2018-07-16', '2018-02-06', NA) ,
  ddn = c('1985-03-14', NA,'1952-02-02', '1961-01-12','1971-06-19', '1969-08-11','1248-11-09', '1956-08-01','1967-09-16', '1989-09-14', NA),
  weight = c(160L, NA, 165L, 180L, 250L,NA ,175L ,NA ,190L, NA, NA),
  queries = c("ok", "not vailable", "ok", "ok", ">220", "not vailable", "< 1900", "not vailable", "ok", "not vailable", "not vailable"),
  center = c("a","a","b","a", "a","b","b","b", "a","b","a"))

dt_out <- dt_in %>% mutate(weight = as.character(weight)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = c(ddn, weight, survey_dt), names_to = "variable")
```

Note, that I had to convert column `weight` to `character` in order to make this work.

Comment: Hi, Thank you I will try